# if $H$, $K$ subgroups of $G$ and $HK$ subgroup of $G$ then either $H$ or $K $ are normal subgroups of $G$ - proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Trying to prove the following equivalence: 
Let $H$, $K$ $\leq$ $G$ and $HK$ = {$hk$ $\in$ $G$ | $h$ $\in$ $H$ $\land$ $k$ $\in$ $K$ }, 
if $HK \leq G \Leftrightarrow H \unlhd G$ or $K \unlhd H$.

I managed $\Leftarrow$ implication, but cannot figure out a way to approach $\Rightarrow$ implication.

Comment: The other implication is not true. Take for example $H = K$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I see, thank you. I saw the "exercise" and took it for granted.